# Highlight item in two lists when mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `<ul>` lists:

```
Item 1     A5
Item 2     A4
Item 3     A2
Item 4     A1
Item 5     A3
```

Where would I start to write code which when I hover over any `<li>` in either list, it will highlight the Item in the first list and the corresponding A in the second list.

For instance, hovering over "Item 3" in list 1 should highlight both that and "A3" in list 2.

**Important:** The numbers are not present in the text of the lists, that was just to help explain. The actual HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="list1">
    <li id="qq1">dfgfdgfdg</li>
    ....
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
    <li id="aa1">cvbcvbcvb</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IDs will stay in that format, then:

```
$(".list1 li, .list2 li").hover(function () {
    var n = this.id.substr(2);
    $("#qq" + n + ", #aa" + n).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e37Yg/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li#item3').hover(function(){
    $(this, '#A3', '#B1').addClass('hilite');
},function(){
    $(this, '#A3', '#B1').removeClass('hilite');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't look right, A3 and B1 are just examples, they shouldn't be in the code.

Comment: I know that. That is just showing you the sketch of how to do it. Since you didn't show the actual html markup, how can I know what ` id`s are really there?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.list1 li,.list2 li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('hovered');
    $($(this).closest('ul').is('.list1')?'.list2 li':'.list1 li').eq($(this).index())
        .addClass('hovered')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('hovered');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/gmgC7/1/)

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but I think the items may not necessarily be in the same order in both lists.

Comment: I've already accepted my answer on this, so you shouldn't waste any more time on it, but for instance when you hover over "Item 4", "A4" should highlight.